# duplicated titlebar when jquery-ui dialog is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

in my spring application, each one of the sub-pages are displayed in a jquery-ui dialog. Right now, I am facing the following problem: when the window is opened, two titlebars are presented on the screen, like this:

[image]

links for the pages and the `<div>` where this pages are inserted placed in the page dashboard.jsp:

```
<%@ include file="../include/header.jsp" %>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li> <c:url value="/Usuario/listagem" var="usuario"/> <a href="#" class="popup" data-action="${usuario}/1/10/1" data-target="popup-usuario">Usu&aacute;rios</a></li>
            <li> <c:url value="/Permissao/listagem" var="permissao"/> <a href="#" class="popup" data-action="${permissao}/1/10/1" data-target="popup-permissao">Permiss&otilde;es</a></li>
            <li> <c:url value="/Grupo/listagem" var="grupo"/> <a href="#" class="popup" data-action="${grupo}/1/10/1" data-target="popup-grupo">Grupos</a></li>
            <li> <c:url value="/logout" var="logoutUrl"/> <a href="${logoutUrl}">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dialog" id="popup-usuario">
            <div id="text"> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dialog" id="popup-permissao">
            <div id="text"> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dialog" id="popup-grupo">
            <div id="text"> </div>
    </div>

<%@ include file="../include/footer.jsp" %>
```

the javascript code which handle the event click and open the jquery-ui dialog is that:

```
$( ".dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      closeOnEscape: true,
      closeText: "fechar",
      show: {
        effect: "fadeIn",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "fadeOut",
        duration: 1000
      },
      close: function( event, ui ) {
          $(this).remove();
      }
});
function open_dialog(url, dialog_box) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url
    }).done(function(data){
        var $temp  = $('<div/>', {html:data});

        $( dialog_box ).dialog( { title: $temp.find('title').text() } );
        $( dialog_box ).find('#text').empty();
        $( dialog_box ).find('#text').html( $temp.remove('head').html() );
        $( dialog_box ).dialog( { height: 680 } );
        $( dialog_box ).dialog( { width: 1046 } );
        $( dialog_box ).dialog( "open" );
    });
}
$(document).on('click', '.popup', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var action = $(this).data('action');
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    var div = $("#"+target);
    open_dialog(action, div);
});
```

anyone can see what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Try adding `event.stopPropagation();` at the top of your `click` handler. Maybe the clicks are bubbling up and firing your `open_dialog()` twice.

Comment: @RodneyGolpe I try that, but don't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already instantiate your dialogs on page load. You are duplicating that in `open_dialog()` when all you really want is to set some options, like so:

```
$( dialog_box ).dialog("option", "title", $temp.find('title').text());
$( dialog_box ).dialog("option", "height", 680);
$( dialog_box ).dialog("option", "width", 1046);
```

But, since your height and width are not specific to any dialog, you should hard code them in your first call to `.dialog()` with those other options (autoOpen, closeOnEscape, etc).

Comment: Ok, you answer made sense to me. One last thing: in this case, **where** I should add the content to dialog? in the handler for the clicm event or in the function open_dialog? or should be in another place?

Comment: Seems fine where you have it. Couple of other things to note:
 1. you don't need to wrap `dialog_box` inside `$()` because it's already a jQuery object; and 2. change all `id="text"` to `class="text"`, and change your associate jQuery selectors to `.find(".text")`.

Comment: OK, I try what you sugest. When I don't wrap `dialog_box`, only the titlebar is displayed. With the `$()`, the first windows is displayed correctly, and the other display a extra title bar (like shown in the picture).

Comment: I don't really know what could be wrong. Here's my solution (everything except your `.ajax()` call):  http://jsfiddle.net/rodgolpe/E84sv/

Comment: right now, I try again without the `$()` and with `$( dialog_box ).dialog("option", "title", $temp.find('title').text())` instead of `$( dialog_box ).dialog( { title: $temp.find('title').text() } )`, and only the title is displayed. I notice in the Inspector from browser (I am using firefox), each time I open a window, a new block  of code is added to the page (with the three blocks `<div>` from class `dialog`).

Comment: my current code: https://github.com/klebermo/blog.cms/blob/master/src/main/webapp/resources/extra/js/page_link.js

Comment: Throw out all that `add_dialog()` stuff. Your very first call to `$(".dialog").dialog()` is all you need, and then you're just opening and closing them. DO NOT `.remove()` the dialog on close! Then you can't reuse it -- you're always recreating it.

Comment: right now, I have another problem, described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325589/unwanted-propagation-for-event-click-with-jquery-inside-spring-application.

Comment: and I think I need the add_dialog() function because I need be able to open several dialogs simultaneously, if I hard-coded the `<div>` used to define the dialog, each time I open a new page, it will replace the  one currently opened.